# Update repository Head with latest files from live server

Tags: svn

Is there a way (or a command) to compare/update the Head of an svn repository with the latest files from the live server?

May seem counterintuitive, my intention is to account for changes that occur via FTP. Obviously the purpose of Subversion control is to track changes and not edit files via FTP, but it can't always be avoided.

Comment: You want to make changes to files on some ftp server and then find those changes and checkin the diffs to a subversion repository?

Comment: What do you mean by "it can't always be avoided"? Certainly that is possible. That is an organizational question.

Answer (score 0):

`svn diff` on the live server should tell you what you need to know.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way (or a command) to compare/update the Head of an svn repository with the latest files from the live server?

You **must** to avoid it: to have *one authoritative source* of changes is *good style* of development, others - bad.

If LiveServer isn't additional WorkingCopy of repository, sync will be handwork

- Copy server-tree locally
- Compare tree of WorkingCopy (updated to HEAD) and SiteRoot-dir
- Copy changed files to WC
- Commit

Last, but not least - **never touch live site after it directly**